# VSTS Task Group Powershell Parameter

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I created VSTS Task Group with Azure Powershell Task Inline Script with Four Parameters. I have added this Task Group to Release Definition and configured parameters. When i try to release it failed with following error

> 2018-03-23T10:28:42.2811600Z ##[error]At
>   C:\Users\buildguest\AppData\Local\Temp\6e927620-8956-47d6-b926-00d9177a4c26.ps1:2
>   char:9
>   + [String] Container-Service,
>   +         ~ Parameter declarations are a comma-separated list of variable names with optional initializer expressions.
>
> At
>   C:\Users\buildguest\AppData\Local\Temp\6e927620-8956-47d6-b926-00d9177a4c26.ps1:2
>   char:9
>   + [String] Container-Service,
>   +         ~ Missing ')' in function parameter list.

Here is Azure Powershell Script

```
 Param(  
[String] $(apiManagementRg),   
[String] $(apiManagementName),     
[String] $(swaggerUrl),     
[String] $(basePath),   
[String] $(apiId)
)

$ApiMgmtContext = New-AzureRmApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName $(apiManagementRg) -ServiceName $(apiManagementName)
Import-AzureRmApiManagementApi -Context $ApiMgmtContext -SpecificationFormat "Swagger" -SpecificationUrl $(swaggerUrl) -Path $(basePath) -ApiId $(apiId)
```

Release Definition Screenshot
[Release Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6qAf.png)

Comment: Please show us how you pass the Arguments to the inline script.

Comment: You can also create an issue here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues

Comment: You should also clarify whether it works outside of a task group

Comment: @MartinBrandl I have edited my question and attached Release definition screenshot

Comment: @bryanmac yes. If add Azure powershell task in Release definition and add these script and replace parameters with actual values.

Comment: What exactly is `$(something)` supposed to mean? What are the parentheses for?

Comment: Without parentheses, parameters textbox not generating in Task Group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's mainly caused by the PowerShell script syntax errors.

Based on your script, it seems `$(apiManagementRg)`, `$(apiManagementName)`, `$(swaggerUrl)`, `$(basePath)` and `$(apiId)` are variables defined in your release definition.

To use the user defined variables from the release definition into Powershell script parameters, you should specify the user defined variables in **Script Arguments** to pass the values into your PowerShell parameters.

Detail steps as below:

- Remove the task group you created.
- Re-create task group with Azure PowerShell Task as below:

  Inline Script:

  ```
  Param(  
  [String] $Rg,   
  [String] $Name,     
  [String] $Url,     
  [String] $path,   
  [String] $apiId
  )

  $ApiMgmtContext = New-AzureRmApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName $Rg -ServiceName $Name
  Import-AzureRmApiManagementApi -Context $ApiMgmtContext -SpecificationFormat "Swagger" -SpecificationUrl $url -Path $path -ApiId $apiId
  ```

  Script Arguments:

  ```
  -Rg "$(apiManagementRg)" -Name "$(apiManagementName)" -Url "$(swaggerUrl)" -path "$(basePath)" -apiId "$(apiId)"
  ```

  [image]

Comment: Is there an example of using args with the v2 version?

Comment: I'd like to see that as well. Can't seem to make it work with the v2 version. In fact, the build fails with: "The term 'Param' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program."