# Escaping parameters for powershell VSTS Task

Tags: azure-devops

Related (but does not answer this case): [VSTS Task Group Powershell Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49447813/vsts-task-group-powershell-parameter)

Question: how do I pass parameter with double quotes and other potentially uncomfortable values (like mix of single and double quotes and other special characters)

I don't know what parameter may be. So need a guaranteed way of escaping arbitraty input.

For example, when passing parameter like this

```
-ParamName "$(ParamValue)"
```

And the value like this:

```
[ "abc=xyz", "abc=somethingelse" ]
```

I got the following:

```
2018-10-03T17:51:53.3159259Z Generating script.
2018-10-03T17:51:53.3257527Z Formatted command: . 'M:\<...>\blah.ps1' -ParamName "[ "abc=xyz", "abc=somethingelse" ]" <...>
2018-10-03T17:51:53.3969661Z ##[command]"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'M:\...\_temp\14d05e56-d7c7-4db9-8007-a29f5b024b51.ps1'"
2018-10-03T17:51:53.7924531Z M:\<...>\blah.ps1 : A 
2018-10-03T17:51:53.7924970Z positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'abc=xyz, abc=somethingelse ]'.
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to solve your current problem the first is to simply use single quotes when you pass the param, e.g.:

`-ParamName '$(ParamValue)'`

The other way is to escape the double quotes in the parameter value using the "`" character (known as the backtick, backquote, or grave-accent). So the value changes from:

`[ "abc=xyz", "abc=somethingelse" ]`

to:

`` [ `"abc=xyz`", `"abc=somethingelse`" ] ``

This way the first double quote in the parameter value won't be interpreted as the end of the string.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. Let's assume I have no control over parameter value (or unwilling to force that requirement on users). As to use single quotes, please see the original quesion - the parameter can have single quotes too

Comment: Basically please note that I'm looking for generic solution - no assumptions about parameter, it should work for any value

Comment: The backtick is the general escape character in powershell and you have control over how params are passed, so use single quotes to prevent variable expansion with the $ character and use the `$var.replace()` function to escape single quotes, #, and any other special characters in the value. You can chain these calls together to do this in a single line.